# MongoDB Aggregation - Possible to have an OR operator in a group function?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to perform an aggregate on a mongodb collection. The issue I'm having is that I need to do an OR operation in a group function.

My documents have different keys for values where ideally they should be the same. I'm stuck with these values so I cannot just normalise the data.

For example the collection has three different field values for an email field :

```
{
  _id : 1,
  name : "docType1",
  e_mail : "joe@example.com"
}
 {
  _id : 2,
  name : "docType2",
  email : "joe@example.com"
}
 {
  _id : 3,
  name : "docType3",
  mail : "joe@example.com"
}
```

Is it possible to perform a group function that groups the documents by the email values once the key is either e_mail, email or mail?

Perhaps its possible in combination with a project but I've been unsuccessful in my attempts so far is I think I would also need an OR here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible with the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/). You basically need to test with the [**`$ifNull`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) operator and use the second condition in a nested form:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": { "$ifNull": [
            "$e_mail",
            { "$ifNull": [
                 "$email",
                 { "$ifNull": [
                     "$mail",
                     false
                 ]}
            ]}
        ]},
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    { "$match": { "_id": { "$ne": false } } }
])
```

So the `$ifNull` takes two arguments, the first being the field to test which is returned where it exists or is not null, and the second is the alternate value to return where the condition is not `true`.

Comment: This satisfies the contraints I have. The only issue I can see is if for some reason "docType2" would have a field called e_mail and email. It would try and group docType2 using the e_mail field where it should use the email field. I know this particular example isn't great but it is a possible scenario in the data I have and thought I'd highlight it for anyone else looking at the same issue.